# Add link in datatable cell

Tags: datatables

How can I add **html tags** inside a column of the datatable?

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "ajax/lista_bozze.php",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
    { "data": "num_ticket" },
    { "data": "cod_pro" },
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "rag_soc" },
    { "data": "date_ticket" },
    { "data": "cod_pro" }
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render` option to process the data inside a datatable column,
this is example of converting one column into a link:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Comment: But in my case (ajax)?

Comment: @AnuFurlan, have you tried before asking? There is no difference.